# How to send XML file using Faraday gem and getting response in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, faraday

I learning how to send http requests, and I want to send whole XML file using Faraday gem and getting response

This is what i found, how i can send a whole file using faraday (faraday gem already installed)

```
faraday = Faraday.new do |f|
    f.request :multipart 
    f.request :url_encoded 
    f.adapter :net_http
end
    file_io = Faraday::UploadIO.new('act.xml', 'rb')
    faraday.post('example.com', file_io)
```

And after that i got this message in console 
.....rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/faraday-0.15.4/lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:12:in `[]': odd number of arguments for Hash (ArgumentError)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
faraday = Faraday.new do |f|
  f.request :multipart 
  f.request :url_encoded 
  f.adapter :net_http
end

payload = {xml: Faraday::UploadIO.new('act.xml', 'application/xml')}
faraday.post('http://example.com', payload)
```

Comment: @user:1688322 Thank you I write it, now it working but there are no response in a console. So i add `puts faraday.post()` And now it said, that *Failed to open TCP connection to :80 (Connection refused - connect(2) for nil port 80)*